# Arduino obstacle-avoiding car

Tags: arduino, l293d

I have built an Arduino obstacle-avoiding car.

After uploading the code, the car does not move.

It beeps for three seconds, waits three seconds and repeats continuously.

I am using a 9V battery connected to the Arduino DC power jack and one 9V battery in PWR EXT.

Parts I have used:

- Arduino Uno
- L293D motor driver
- 4 DC motors
- servo motor

Comment: All very interesting, Ali, but what is your question? And if you have a question how do you expect us to diagnose the problem with no code and no schematic? In any case this seems like a problem for https://arduino.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Run some firmware that proves the car can actually move. Learn how to diagnose stuff.

Comment: Neither a 9v battery nor an L293 is suitable for this.  Get six AA's and an FET bridge.

Comment: Block the sensor or emitter and see if it moves with a Lithium 9V

Comment: Well .. technically you've succeeded. If it never moves it'll also never hit any obstacles ...

Answer (score 1):

I expect the "beep" comes from one of the motor, or maybe the servo.

9 volt batteries cannot deliver a lot of current.  Many DC motors and servos need more current than a 9V battery can supply.

You need a battery with the correct voltage and current rating for your motors and the servo.

---

I expect the Arduino tries to drive one or more of the motors (or the servo) - this causes the beep.  The Arduino drives the motors with a pulse width modulation (PWM) signal.  At each pulse, the motor tries to turn, but the battery can't deliver enough current to turn the motor.  The motor then just vibrates slightly in reaction to the pulses.

The servo would similarly cause a beep when the current is too low.

It beeps, pauses, and repeats because the load from the motor(s) causes the battery voltage to drop.  The low voltage causes the Arduino to restart.  Arduinos take a couple of seconds to start up.  It goes start, pause, try to move, battery voltage drops, Arduino resets, start, etc.  Repeat until the battery is totally dead.

Comment: What motor driver should i get for this project.(I am a beginner)